# Display Two different UITABLEVIEWCELLS outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two `UITableViewCells` and displaying them based on condition in 
`cellForRowatIndexPath`. Both cells related to a creation of a post and than displaying them in `UITableView`.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method i don't have any issues to use condition to display cell.

*For example:*

```
if postType[indexPath.row] == "Regular" {show this sell } 
else {show another}`
```

This is working perfect. `postType` array is created during the post creation.

The issue that i have is to show a proper cell outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

I have a button and when user click on it they would be going to the proper cell, just like they would click on the cell it self. However I don't know how to condition an array at proper `indexPath` or maybe there other way. I'm not that good because just starting out to learn swift.

I can do for a one cell but i want a condition first and than display a proper cell.

This statement works for a one cell.

```
@IBAction func usernameBtn_click(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let i = sender.layer.value(forKey: "index") as! IndexPath
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: i) as! postCell
}
```

In my case I have two cells. How to have a condition based on post type value in array and have a proper index inserted to check the value and than display a cell.

I have these two cells:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: i) as! postCell
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: i) as! moreinfoCell
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the button does the same as if the user selects the cell so if you have that working just deselect "User Interaction Enable" of your button.

In interface builder:

[image]

Programmatically:

```
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Doing that the touch will be done on the UITableViewCell and the didSelectRowAt indexPath: method will be fired.